# Mysql Rollback Restore

Tags: mysql

A colleague from my office created a backup of MySql database of different location and mistakenly he restored the same to another location server, which had overwritten existing data.

Is there any possibilities to rollback the restore and get the old data back?

Even the backup of that database got corrupted, hence we are not able to restore that again.

Comment: Try to find any older backup, because there is no way to restore database without correct backup file.

Comment: Thanks QArea!! But can't we recover any files from Hard Disk using recovery tool and get back some files and restore it.

Comment: There is a free programm Recuvo. You can try to do this with it. You can download it here: https://www.piriform.com/recuva/download . But, you will be really lucky if you'll restore your database, cause it's really hard.

This app works on Windows – But if your server was on linux, we should find something else.

Comment: I'm not that lucky :( Used the same tool to retrieve but didn't find anything.